# How to use images/text/etc. in XNA without Content Pipeline?

Tags: xna, graphics, textures, xna-content-pipeline

I'm currently writing a program in C# with the XNA framework. It is absolutely necessary for the game's images and text assets to be visible by the end user in the form of PNG files, so I can't use the content pipeline.

How would I go about using graphics and text in my XNA game without it?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the content pipeline.

MonoGame, for example, allows you to use `LoadContent<Texture2D>` and specify an image name of a file that's just a simple PNG in your `Content` directory. This is what I do for all my projects (since MonoGame has difficult/flakey? support of the content pipeline today), and because I don't care about "protecting" my assets by converting them into `XN*` format.

From what I remember of "vanilla" or MS XNA, this worked there too.

Comment: Note that you don't need to store the raw PNG and other content in the `Content` directory, and that textures that you load in this fashion do not have pre-multiplied alphas, so this will need to be done manually. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078206/what-are-the-risks-of-loading-textures-from-images-at-runtime-in-xna/12080397#12080397) for a method that does this.

Comment: @JohnMcDonald I'm not sure if this is true. I have no problem with pre-multiplied alphas, albeit you have to set the spritebatch `BlendState` to `Non-Premultiplied`. See my question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44696/alpha-from-pngs-butchered

Comment: Makes sense, either multiply the alphas yourself, or tell XNA that the alphas haven't been pre-multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

Use Texture.FromStream to load the texture at runtime. This is a little tricky because of premultiplied alpha as referred to in ashes999 answer. [Here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25786/using-xna-contentpipeline-to-export-a-file-in-a-machine-without-full-xna-gs) is a great explanation from David Gouveia on how to do it correctly